# eval(babel.transform('<div>gf</div>').code) throws Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, meteor, eval, babeljs, reactjs

I am trying to do this bad thing in my react app

```
import babel from 'babel-core'

const MyComponent = eval(babel.transform('<div>gf</div>').code)
```

However I get this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (1:0)
> 1 | <div>gf</div>
    | ^
```

I have installed these packages

```
"babel-core": "^6.25.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
```

But still get the error, do you have an idea why does this happen?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Babel to use the `react` preset:

```
const MyComponent = eval(babel.transform('<div>gf</div>', { presets : [ 'react' ] }).code)
```

(which may also require importing `react`)

Comment: Hi Robert thanks for the answer.
I get this error now `Uncaught Error: Couldn't find preset "react" relative to directory "/"`
I imported react like this `import React, { Component } from 'react'`

Comment: You said you installed `babel-preset-react`, but Babel is complaining it can't find it. Try installing it again: `npm install babel-preset-react`

Comment: I did so to make it double sure. But nothings changed. By the way I'm using Meteor. And now it complains as if there are bunch of not installed modules but all of them worked fine before installing babel stuff... Do you have any idea about this dear Robert?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I know that Meteor isn't "regular Node", so to speak, so perhaps it's doing something funky.